Get all Profile defaults (record type, app, page assignments) into a CSV
I'm looking at migrating from Profiles to Permission Sets for most permissions in my org, in keeping with official Salesforce best practice.
One important part of this is consolidating Profiles. But Record Type defaults, App defaults, Page Layout assignments, and Lightning Page assignments are all defined at the Profile level, so first I need to evaluate how these differ among existing Profiles.
I want all this metadata exported to a spreadsheet. I'm pretty sure it can't be queried with SOQL. I think the Metadata API can get me there, but working with Profiles in the Metadata API gets complicated, and I'm sure I'm not the only person facing this problem who could benefit from having this task unpacked a bit. (I'll unpack it myself if I come up with a solution before someone else provides a good answer here).
I'm open-minded regarding technological approach: Apex Execute Anonymous, Workbench, Bash script, Node.js, Python, Java, browser scraping, VS Code hacks, etc.

I managed to get all my Profile-related App defaults, Record Type defaults, Page Layout assignments, and Lightning Page overrides into a CSV using Node.js scripting in my local SFDX project and TypeScript.
Prerequisites

Node.js and Salesforce CLI installed locally. You can check both of these by running sf version in a terminal. My output looks like this:

@salesforce/cli/2.43.7 win32-x64 node-v20.10.0


A Node.js project. Create a new directory and run npm init inside it, or leverage an existing SFDX project, which should already be set up for Node.js.
Node.js dependencies installed. You can run:

npm install --save-dev jsforce@3 unzipper @types/unzipper fast-xml-parser csv-stringify fs-extra @types/fs-extra typescript ts-node

Note: most Node.js projects also benefit from packages like eslint and prettier that come with SFDX

The script configured in your package.json, e.g.:

"scripts": {
    ...
    "getProfileDefaults": "ts-node scripts/node/getProfileDefaults"
},


Your Salesforce CLI default org set to the org you want to pull from. Run sf config list to check the current default org. Run sf org list to see what org connections you have available, and sf config set target-org {USERNAME_OR_ORG_ALIAS} to change to a different default org. If you aren't yet connected to the org, you can log in with sf org login web --set-default.

The code
Create the following file:
scripts/node/getProfileDefaults.ts
import jsforce from "jsforce";
import { exec } from "child_process";
import { promisify } from "util";
import unzipper from "unzipper";
import { XMLParser } from "fast-xml-parser";
import { stringify as csvStringify } from "csv-stringify/sync";
import * as fs from "fs-extra";
import type {
  FileProperties,
  Package,
  RetrieveRequest,
  RetrieveResult
} from "jsforce/lib/api/metadata";

const _exec = promisify(exec);

enum DefaultType {
  Application,
  RecordType,
  PageLayout,
  LightningPage
}

type ProfileDefault = {
  ProfileName: string;
  Type: DefaultType;
  PageOrSobjectType?: string;
  RecordType?: string;
  Application?: string;
  FormFactor?: string;
  ActionName?: string;
  DefaultValue: string;
};

type RecordType = {
  Id: string;
  DeveloperName: string;
  SobjectType: string;
};

type CustomApp = {
  Id: string;
  Name: string;
};

// MAIN METHOD
const run = async () => {
  // Call Salesforce CLI command to get session information
  const { stdout } = await _exec(`sf org display --json`);
  const org = JSON.parse(stdout.toString());
  const { alias, instanceUrl, username, accessToken, apiVersion } = org.result;
  console.info(
    `Connected to ${alias} (${instanceUrl}) with username ${username} and API version number ${apiVersion}`
  );

  // Create a new jsforce Connection instance
  const conn = new jsforce.Connection({ instanceUrl, accessToken });

  // Because the Metadata API doesn't support wildcards for RecordType, first
  // query to retrieve all record types in the org
  const recordTypes: RecordType[] = (
    await conn.query<RecordType>(
      "SELECT Id, DeveloperName, SobjectType FROM RecordType"
    )
  ).records;

  // The Metadata API also does not support wildcards for retrieving Lightning
  // Page profile overrides via Custom Apps: retrieve all app names
  const customApps: FileProperties[] = await conn.metadata.list(
    [{ type: "CustomApplication", folder: null }],
    apiVersion
  );

  // Build the package definition (similar to package.xml)
  const pkg: Package = {
    objectPermissions: [],
    types: [
      {
        name: "CustomApplication",
        members: customApps.map((app) => app.fullName)
      },
      {
        name: "RecordType",
        members: recordTypes.map(
          (rt) => `${rt.SobjectType}.${rt.DeveloperName}`
        )
      },
      { name: "Layout", members: ["*"] },
      { name: "CustomObject", members: ["*"] },
      { name: "FlexiPage", members: ["*"] },
      { name: "Profile", members: ["*"] }
    ],
    version: apiVersion
  };

  // Create the Metadata API retrieve request
  const retrieveReq: RetrieveRequest = {
    apiVersion: parseInt(apiVersion),
    packageNames: [],
    singlePackage: true,
    specificFiles: [],
    unpackaged: pkg
  };

  // Call the Metadata API, returning the retrieve job ID
  console.info("Initiating Metadata API retrieve job for package: ", pkg);
  const retrieveLocator = await conn.metadata.retrieve(retrieveReq);

  // Poll for results
  let result: RetrieveResult;
  let done = false;
  let pollCount = 1;
  while (!done) {
    console.info(
      `Polling Metadata API retrieve job (${pollCount}): ${retrieveLocator.id}`
    );
    result = await conn.metadata.checkRetrieveStatus(retrieveLocator.id);
    done = result.done;
    // Wait 2 seconds in between checks
    if (!done) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      pollCount++;
    }
  }

  console.info(`Unzipping metadata with size: ${result!.zipFile.length}`);
  // Unzip the package in the responsse
  const directory: unzipper.CentralDirectory = await unzipper.Open.buffer(
    Buffer.from(result!.zipFile, "base64")
  );

  // Iterate through the files in the directory, collecting default settings
  const defaults: ProfileDefault[] = [];
  const parser = new XMLParser();
  for (const file of directory.files) {
    console.info(`Found file: ${file.path}`);
    // For each profile...
    if (file.path.startsWith("profiles")) {
      // Get the profile name
      const profileName: string = file.path
        .replace("profiles/", "")
        .replace(".profile", "");

      const fileBuffer = await file.buffer();
      const data = parser.parse(fileBuffer.toString());

      // Get the default Application for this profile
      defaults.push({
        ProfileName: profileName,
        Type: DefaultType.Application,
        DefaultValue: data.Profile.applicationVisibilities.find(
          (app: any) => app.default
        ).application
      });

      // Get the default record types per SObject for this profile
      for (const rtv of data.Profile.recordTypeVisibilities) {
        const { sobjectName, recordTypeName } = parseRecordType(rtv.recordType);
        if (rtv.default) {
          defaults.push({
            ProfileName: profileName,
            Type: DefaultType.RecordType,
            PageOrSobjectType: sobjectName,
            DefaultValue: recordTypeName
          });
        }
      }

      const layoutAssignments: any[] = [].concat(
        data.Profile.layoutAssignments
      );

      // Get the assigned page layouts per SObject + record type
      for (const pla of layoutAssignments) {
        let sobjectName: string | undefined;
        let recordTypeName: string | undefined;
        // If this layout is assigned to a specific record type, parse out the
        // SObject and Record Type names
        if (pla.recordType) {
          const rt = parseRecordType(pla.recordType);
          sobjectName = rt.sobjectName;
          recordTypeName = rt.recordTypeName;
        }
        // Otherwise, this is the default layout for this SObject + Profile.
        // Parse the SObject name from the layout name. Layout names look like
        // this: "Project__c-SI Project Layout"
        else {
          sobjectName = pla.layout.split("-")[0];
          recordTypeName = "[DEFAULT]";
        }
        defaults.push({
          ProfileName: profileName,
          Type: DefaultType.PageLayout,
          PageOrSobjectType: sobjectName,
          RecordType: recordTypeName,
          DefaultValue: pla.layout
        });
      }
    } else if (file.path.startsWith("applications")) {
      // Get the app name from the file name
      const appName: string = file.path
        .replace("applications/", "")
        .replace(".app", "");

      // Parse the XML
      const fileBuffer = await file.buffer();
      const data = parser.parse(fileBuffer.toString());

      if (data.CustomApplication.actionOverrides) {
        const overrides: any[] = [].concat(
          data.CustomApplication.actionOverrides
        );
        // Get the default Lightning Pages per app and form factor. We need to
        // compare the Lightning Pages assigned this way with those assigned at
        // the profile + record type level to capture all the differences in
        // user experiences across profiles.
        for (const ao of overrides) {
          if (ao.type === "Flexipage") {
            defaults.push({
              ProfileName: "[APP DEFAULT]",
              Type: DefaultType.LightningPage,
              PageOrSobjectType: ao.pageOrSobjectType,
              RecordType: "[DEFAULT]",
              Application: appName,
              FormFactor: ao.formFactor,
              ActionName: ao.actionName,
              DefaultValue: ao.content
            });
          }
        }
      }

      if (data.CustomApplication.profileActionOverrides) {
        const overrides: any[] = [].concat(
          data.CustomApplication.profileActionOverrides
        );
        // Get the assigned Lightning Pages per app, record type, and form factor
        for (const pao of overrides) {
          defaults.push({
            ProfileName: pao.profile,
            Type: DefaultType.LightningPage,
            PageOrSobjectType: pao.pageOrSobjectType,
            RecordType: pao.recordType,
            Application: appName,
            FormFactor: pao.formFactor,
            ActionName: pao.actionName,
            DefaultValue: pao.content
          });
        }
      }
    } else if (file.path.startsWith("objects")) {
      // Get the app name from the file name
      const objName: string = file.path
        .replace("objects/", "")
        .replace(".object", "");

      // Parse the XML
      const fileBuffer = await file.buffer();
      const data = parser.parse(fileBuffer.toString());

      if (data.CustomObject.actionOverrides) {
        const overrides: any[] = [].concat(data.CustomObject.actionOverrides);
        // Get the default Lightning Page for this object. We need to compare
        // the Lightning Pages assigned this way with those assigned at the app,
        // profile, record type level to capture all the differences in user
        // experiences across profiles.
        for (const ao of overrides) {
          if (ao.type === "Flexipage") {
            defaults.push({
              ProfileName: "[ORG DEFAULT]",
              Type: DefaultType.LightningPage,
              PageOrSobjectType: objName,
              RecordType: "[DEFAULT]",
              Application: "[ALL]",
              FormFactor: ao.formFactor,
              ActionName: ao.actionName,
              DefaultValue: ao.content
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  const csvString = csvStringify(
    defaults.map((x) => ({ ...x, Type: DefaultType[x.Type] })),
    { header: true }
  );
  await fs.outputFile("./tmp/profileDefaults.csv", csvString);
};

const parseRecordType = (fullName: string) => {
  const segments: string[] = fullName.split(".");
  return { sobjectName: segments[0], recordTypeName: segments[1] };
};

run();


Execution
Run this command in the terminal: npm run getProfileDefaults. The script creates a CSV called profileDefaults.csv in the tmp directory (which it also creates if no tmp exists).
